# How to join sets of indexes with pairs of indexes and text

Tags: apache-spark

My Spark Job reads lines from a text file, then adds a unique index for each line using `zipWithIndex`:

```
JavaPairRDD<Long, String> docsWithIndexes = sc
            .textFile("test.txt")
            .zipWithIndex()
            .mapToPair(t -> new Tuple2<Long, String>(t._2, t._1));
```

`docsWithIndexes` contains pairs where key is an index (generated by `zipWithIndex`) and a value which is a text line from the file. 
On a later stage in this job, I collect back into the driver a list of sets of indexes `List<Set<Long>> setsOfDocs`. The indexes in these sets are the same as in `docsWithIndexes`.  What I'd like to achieve is replace the index numbers in each set in `setsOfDocs` with a text line from `docsWithIndexes`, effectively matching each index with its corresponding text line.
I think a `join` has to be involved but I don't know how to do the matching inside each set. I need to keep the sets in tact and not flatten them because eventually I need to write each set separately to an output file as a separate line.
Of course, in the driver I can do `docsWithIndexes.collectAsMap()` and use it to match the indices in `setsOfDocs` which would solve my problem, however that would be brutal in terms of memory consumption. What I want is to perform the index to text matching on my cluster nodes and write the results to HDFS.